# the use of lmfit ExponentialGaussianModel( )

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

Trying to fit `ExponentialGaussianModel()` from `lmfit` but getting the following error message:  `The input contains nan values`

I am using Jupyternotebook on windows and I am new to python and lmfit. I find the lmfit documentation to be a bit obscure for a beginner and hope to find help here. Following is my code: I would like to generate a exponential-gaussian histogram, extract data points and practice fitting with `lmfit` library. ( I would like to practice fitting and finding least number of points that would reproduce the parameters used producing the histogram)

```
from scipy.stats import exponnorm
from lmfit.models import ExponentialGaussianModel

K2 = 1.5
r2 = exponnorm.rvs(K2, size=500, loc = 205, scale = 40)

Q           =  np.histogram(r2,500)
exp_gaus_x  =  Q[1]
exp_gaus_y  =  Q[0]

tof_x       =  exp_gaus_x[1:]
tof_y       =  exp_gaus_y

mod =  ExponentialGaussianModel()
pars = mod.guess(tof_y, x=tof_x)
out  = mod.fit(tof_y, pars, x=tof_x)
(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
```

I get the error that there are nan input values. I was expecting a report like shown in the manual.

Comment: @M Newville: am I right to assume that  gamma in the above fit means tau = 1/gamma; whereas tau  is exponential relaxation time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of exponential Gaussian used in `lmfit` is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution.
With the exponential term being

`exp[center*gamma + (gamma*sigma)**2/2 - gamma*x]`

this has the tendency to give `Inf` for large-ish values of `sigma` and `gamma`, and/or `center`.   I believe that you are getting such `Inf` values and that this is the cause of the `NaN` message you are seeing.  The fitting routines (in Fortran) do not handle `NaN` or `Inf` gracefully (actually, "at all").  This is a real limitation of that particular model. You'll see that the examples on the wikipedia page all have `x` values much closer to `1` than `200`, and `gamma` and `sigma` also on the order of 1, not around 50, which is what the automated `guess` gives.

I think that a simpler definition for an exponentially modified Gaussian would be better for you.  With

```
def expgaussian(x, amplitude=1, center=0, sigma=1.0, gamma=1.0):
    """ an alternative exponentially modified Gaussian."""
    dx = center-x
    return amplitude* np.exp(gamma*dx) * erfc( dx/(np.sqrt(2)*sigma))
```

You'll get a decent fit, though the meaning of the parameters has changed a bit, and you will need to explicitly give starting values, not rely on a `guess()` procedure.  These don't have to be very close, just not very far off.

A full script might be:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import exponnorm
from scipy.special import erfc
from lmfit import Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def expgaussian(x, amplitude=1, center=0, sigma=1.0, gamma=1.0):
    """ an alternative exponentially modified Gaussian."""
    dx = center-x
    return amplitude* np.exp(gamma*dx) * erfc( dx/(np.sqrt(2)*sigma))

K2 = 1.5
r2 = exponnorm.rvs(K2, size=500, loc = 205, scale = 40)
Q           =  np.histogram(r2,500)
exp_gaus_x  =  Q[1]
exp_gaus_y  =  Q[0]
tof_x       =  exp_gaus_x[1:]
tof_y       =  exp_gaus_y

mod =  Model(expgaussian)
pars = mod.make_params(sigma=20, gamma=0.1, amplitude=2, center=250)

out  = mod.fit(tof_y, pars, x=tof_x)

print(out.fit_report())

plt.plot(tof_x, tof_y, label='data')
plt.plot(tof_x, out.best_fit, label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which will print out

```
[[Model]]
    Model(expgaussian)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 65
    # data points      = 500
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 487.546692
    reduced chi-square = 0.98295704
    Akaike info crit   = -4.61101662
    Bayesian info crit = 12.2474158
[[Variables]]
    gamma:      0.01664876 +/- 0.00239048 (14.36%) (init = 0.1)
    sigma:      39.6914678 +/- 3.90960254 (9.85%) (init = 20)
    center:     235.600396 +/- 11.8976560 (5.05%) (init = 250)
    amplitude:  3.43975318 +/- 0.15675053 (4.56%) (init = 2)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(gamma, center)     =  0.930
    C(sigma, center)     =  0.870
    C(gamma, amplitude)  =  0.712
    C(gamma, sigma)      =  0.693
    C(center, amplitude) =  0.572
    C(sigma, amplitude)  =  0.285
```

and show a plot like

[image]

Hope that helps.